# SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier in creating table

Tags: create-table

**SQL Error:** ORA-00904

**MY CODE IS:**

```
CREATE TABLE VINTAGEWINE
(
WINE_ID            VARCHAR2(5)  NOT NULL,
WINE_NAME          VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL
VINTAGE_YEAR       VARCHAR2(4)  NOT NULL,
EMPLOYEE_ID        VARCHAR2(6)  NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_VINTAGEWINE PRIMARY KEY(WINE_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK1-VINTAGEWINE FOREIGN KEY(WINE_NAME) REFERENCES WINE(WINE_NAME),
);
```

**Error:**

```
Error at Command Line:8 Column:14
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code. Did I do something dumb?

Comment: u r right, buddy. Thank u so much.  Mis-clicek made underline into hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

Either `CONSTRAINT FK1-VINTAGEWINE` is illegal, or the `FK1-VINTAGEWINE` must be quoted, I think.  Use an underscore instead of a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE VINTAGEWINE
(
WINE_ID            VARCHAR2(5)  NOT NULL,
WINE_NAME          VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL
VINTAGE_YEAR       VARCHAR2(4)  NOT NULL,
EMPLOYEE_ID        VARCHAR2(6)  NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_VINTAGEWINE PRIMARY KEY(WINE_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK1-VINTAGEWINE FOREIGN KEY(WINE_NAME) REFERENCES WINE(WINE_NAME)
);
```

Please try this. An unwanted comma was inserted at the end of foreign key constraint definition.